# Why is the seed not at the top of the file and clearly identified when dumping a wallet in bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core

When I dump my wallet in bitcoin core:

```
bitcoin-cli dumpwallet mywallet.txt
```

The output looks like this, obfuscating keys with `XXX`

```
# Wallet dump created by Bitcoin v0.21.0
# * Created on 2021-08-12T17:19:57Z
# * Best block at time of backup was 695445 (00000000000000000004f27a30ca376652c836a0c498d1c93ced4727e94074d0),
#   mined on 2021-08-12T17:15:35Z

# extended private masterkey: xprv9XXXXX

XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qq9XXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/50'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qq9XXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/200'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qqfXXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/238'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qq0XXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/134'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qq0XXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/174'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qqjXXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/58'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qq5XXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/159'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qqkXXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/153'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qqhXXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/62'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z hdseed=1 # addr=bc1qqaXXX
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qq7XXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/127'
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z reserve=1 # addr=bc1qqlXXX hdkeypath=m/0'/0'/205'
```

As a new user, I would think that based on the structure of this file the important part to backup is **# extended private masterkey: xprv9XXXXX**

However, this is not the case [according to this answer for storing the seed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91156/backup-of-a-bitcoind-wallet-using-the-extended-private-masterkey-only), the important part is the `hdseed`:

```
XXX 2021-08-12T12:29:33Z hdseed=1 # addr=bc1qqaXXX
```

The **XXX** portion from above.

Why is that not made clearer in the output of `dumpwallet`?

Comment: Even I had this question few days back but then assumed maybe it's good for security. Curious to know the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dumpwallet RPC was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/4e534aa9d892dd6db64afda979ba1f8d44371389), in the v0.9 release of Bitcoin Core.

This was back in time when the wallet was just a random bag of independent keys. That is, before HD wallets came along. So there was no such thing as a seed, hence the dumpfile being simply a long list of keys.

Since HD wallets were introduced, no-one has modified this RPC to put the seed at the top. That's all there is to it :)

Comment: Not to mention that the seed by itself was not useful for a long time as there was no way to import a seed and set the wallet to use a particular seed.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody<sup>†</sup> knows.

The *motivation* for features in Bitcoin core is rarely documented in easily accessible places - though you might examine the source code for hints. It might be, for example, that the original author of `dumpwallet` felt that `backupwallet` was adequate for people seeking to preserve the seed and that they intended `dumpwallet` as a debugging aid for developers and not as a way for end-users to make a note of their seed for recovery purposes. If so, for this debugging purpose, the lack of prominence of the seed is unimportant.

---

Footnotes:

<sup>†</sup> Approximately. Presumably the original author knew at the time they implemented the dumpwallet feature but they may have forgotten or died.

Comment: verify = `dumpwallet`, trust = `backupwallet`

Comment: Actually, sipa introduced the dumpwallet RPC: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/4e534aa9d892dd6db64afda979ba1f8d44371389 (he definitely hasn't died I hope!)

Comment: Not the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Glad to hear it :-)

Answer (score -2):

The most important bit is the master seed, which is at the top of the file. A user deciding what parts of a backup file are "important" to them isn't really a consideration regardless.

Comment: As OP points out, the seed is not at the top of the file.